# ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.23 : Cannot use SQL CAST function with layer.definitionExpression but it work fine with query builder

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, datetime, timestamp

I'm working with features which needs to be filtered.

I need to use the definition expression : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-SceneLayer.html#definition...

I want to use ISO dates so I'm using moment to get the ISO and try to use :

```sql
date < CAST('2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z' AS DATE)
```

It worked fine with query builder and also definition query in Pro so I'm assuming it work on JS API's definitonExpression to but it said I use a non-standard function.

I'm able to find a workaround by reformating my dates after convert with the .toIsoString() funciton and using but I still want to be clean and only convert to ISO / sending a cast as date.

```js
const dateMax = '2019-12-31 23:00:00.000'
layer.definitionExpression = `dateStart < timestamp '${dateMax}'`
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I can't seem to find the right documentation right now, but I think that with the JavaScript API, you are limited to the [Standardized SQL Functions](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/sql-agol.htm). For datefields you could use either `<DateField> = DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `<DateField> = TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'`

Comment: Yes its the workaround i find my post was not good fot the maxDate sorry its edited. I will explore the link thanks !